# How to parse multiple styled paragraph from ms word using apache poi?

Tags: parsing, ms-word, apache-poi, apache-tika

MS Word supports to merge two styled paragraph to one paragraph, but how to parse the two paragraphs and how to know what was merged with apache poi or orther libraries?

Comment: Are you trying to detect when two paragraphs were merged? Or just read the paragraph as a normal multi-styled paragraph and get the different bits of text with their styles?

Comment: I'm fetching the paragraphs and reading specific paragraph but I don't know what do you mean that the getting the different bits of text? Can you give an example?

Comment: In the Word file formats, a paragraph is made up of 1+ runs of text. Everything in a run has the same style. So, iterate over the runs in your paragraph, and fetch the styling from the runs?

Comment: No, my paragraphs has nested styles, like that: `<p class=Prg><span class=PrgLinkChar>link_content: </span> paragraph content</p>` and need to get content of `PrgLinkChar` and also content of `Prg`.

Comment: OK, so grab the runs, check the styles, and grab the text from the runs of interest? BTW Word internally doesn't have anything like a HTML representation....

Comment: The html is from my converted the word document, it's an example of how it looks the style separated paragraphs in word. So you're right, normal paragraphs have only one style but, style separated paragraphs have multi-styles and I don't know how to reach and parse child paragraph's styles and texts from root paragraph. If there are a way to do that, explain with example please.